# hard-drive SATA 3 compatiblity

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [6Gb/s SATA hard drive with 3Gb/s SATA port?](https://superuser.com/questions/242423/6gb-s-sata-hard-drive-with-3gb-s-sata-port)

A hardisk SATA 3 will work on a motherboard with SATA 2 cables and controller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hard drive is backward compatible, it will run at Sata 2 speeds though.

Similar to these posts

[6Gb/s SATA hard drive with 3Gb/s SATA port?](https://superuser.com/questions/242423/6gb-s-sata-hard-drive-with-3gb-s-sata-port)

[Can I connect a SATA-II hard drive to a SATA-I connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/52001/can-i-connect-a-sata-ii-hard-drive-to-a-sata-i-connection)